A confusion of Rudin's proof of Riesz representation theorem
For a locally compact Hausdorff space $(X, \tau)$, $C_c(X)$ is a dense ideal of $C_0(X)$. For a closed set $K\subset X$, we denote
$$C_c(K,\cdot):=\left\{f\in C_c(X): f(X)\subset [0,1], K\subset f^{-1}\left(\left\{0\right\}\right)\right\}.$$
Let $\Lambda: C_c(X)\to \mathbb{C}$ be a positive linear functional. Define set function
$$\mu(E):=
   \begin{cases}
    \sup\left\{\Lambda \left(f\right): f\in C_c\left(X\setminus E, \cdot\right)\right\},& \text{ for }E\in \tau\\
    \inf\left\{\mu(U): E\subset U\in \tau\right\},& \text{ for }E\subset X
   \end{cases}.$$

Question. How is it possible, for a set $E\subset X$, to have $\mu(E)=\infty$?

If I'm not mistaken, as a positive linear functional, $\Lambda$ is bounded. Hence for any set $E$, $|\Lambda(f)|\leq \|\Lambda\|\|f\|\leq \|\Lambda\|$, since $f\in C_c(X\setminus E,\cdot)\Rightarrow \|f\|\leq 1$. Thus, $\mu(E)\leq \|\Lambda\|$ for all $E\subset X$.
However, in step I of Rudin's proof (Real and Complex analysis, p.42) of the Riesz representation theorem, it's mentioned that it's possible to have an $E$ s.t. $\mu(E)=\infty$. Hence the question.
Thanks in advance.
Update. It seems this answers my core confusion:

the unitization of $C_c(X)$ is dense in the unitization of $C_0(X)$;

if $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$, it may not be positively extended to $C_0(X)$;

if $\Lambda$ doesn't have a positive extension on $C_0(X)$, by considering the one-point compactification of $X$, it cannot have a positive extension to constant function $1$ on the compactification;

the usual proof of positive linear functional on a unital C*-algebra doesn't work on $\Lambda$ (since it has no positive extension on the unitizatization).



It does not seem to be specified that $\Lambda$ is continuous, thus you could have $| \Lambda |=\infty$, however if it was continuous I don’t see any flaw in your reasoning. Also what norm do you use? The uniform norm on $C^0$ ?

@julio_es_sui_glace $\Lambda$ is automatically bounded, since it's positive. The usual proof is $\Lambda(\overline{f}g)$ defines an inner-product $\langle g, f\rangle$ on $C_c(X)$, and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives $|\Lambda|=\Lambda(1)$. Although this is for unital C*-algebras, but it suffices to apply this on the unitalization of $C_c(X)$ and nowhere in the proof is completeness used.
Yes, I'm using the sup-norm.

If $X$ is just a Locally Compact Hausdorff space, a positive linear functional in $C_c(X)$ may not be bounded in the uniform norm. Consider the functional $\Lambda: C_c(\Bbb R)\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\Lambda(f) = \int f d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional, but, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $|\chi_{[0,n]}|\infty =1$ and $\Lambda(\chi{[0,n]}) =n$. So, $\Lambda$ is not bounded.  For such $\Lambda$, is is easy to see that, if $E= (0, +\infty)$, then $\mu(E) = \infty$.

@Ramiro That's exactly why I ask this question. Simple counterexample like Lebesgue measure and $X=\mathbb{R}$ suffices. But what went wrong with the "proof" of positive $\Lambda$ being bounded? Is the lack of $1$ the issue here? But if $\Lambda$ is bounded on the unitization, why isn't it also bounded on $C_c(X)$?

Yes, the proof that "a positive linear functional is bounded" requires the $1$.  Without $1$, the proof does not work.  Regarding the unitization, not all positive functional in $C_c(X)$ extends to its unitization.

Usually, $C_c(X)$ is not endowed with the topology induced by that of $C_0(X)$, but with another topology which in general isn't normable… If you did read somewhere that positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ are always continuous: it's true, but you need to consider the correct topology for that.

@P.P.Tuong Is it the compact-open topology you are talking about?

@user760 No, it's a little complicated to describe: for every compact subset $K$ of $X$, let $$C_K(X)={f\in C_c(X)~|~\operatorname{supp}f\subset K}$$ and endow it with the topology of uniform convergence; the usual topology on $C_c(X)$ is then the "final locally convex topology" with respect to the injections $C_K(X)\to C_c(X)$.

@P.P.Tuong I have some vague memory of what's called "direct limit", and it seems to be what you suggest. But I'll have to go back and check books. Thanks for reminding me!

Let me be more precise. There are proofs that "a positive linear functional is bounded" is true in a C-* algebra even if it is not unital. However, such proofs use the completeness of the C-* algebra. So such proofs don't apply to  $C_c(X)$ with the uniform topology, because it is not complete, and again, not all positive functional in $C_c(X)$ extends to its completion ($C_0(X)$).
